# install4j stop unix service launcher timeout

Tags: restart, install4j

Is it possible to increase the time when calling stop or restart on a generated linux/unix service launcher, before the call fails saying that the call timed-out?  I found that on windows you have to edit the registry since its implemented as a Windows Service, but couldn't find any information on changing the timeout on linux/unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the timeout is 120 seconds. For Linux/Unix service launchers, you can set the VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.daemonTimeout=600
```

to increase it to 600 seconds.

Comment: Is it possible to set that property as part of building the installer, or does one have to edit the generated service launcher to add the parameter?  I tried adding the property to my launchers vmoptions file, but it doesn't look  like the generated service launcher uses the vmoptions for the stop operation.

Comment: In 6.1.3, this is a bug, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is fixed.